# MONGO_QUERY_BLACKLIST doesn't work

Tags: python, mongodb, eve

I'm using python-eve with default settings where

```
'MONGO_QUERY_BLACKLIST': ['$where', '$regex']
```

But it appears that I still can use 'where'-parameter in queries to Eve.

```
import requests

params = {'where': '{"username":"Alex"}'}
response = requests.get('http://localhost/users', params)
print response.content
print response.status_code
```

> {"_items": [{"username": "Alex", ... }], ...}
>
> 200

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are conflating Eve's REST API parameter called `where` (which translates the given parameters into query criteria for a standard MongoDB  [`find()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) query) with MongoDB's  [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/)  JavaScript operator (whose usage is strongly discouraged and disabled by default in Eve).

This is an unfortunately confusing naming choice in the Eve API. The `$where` operator (if used) would be part of the query criteria provided to Eve's `where`.

Modifying your example params to use a `$where` query (for illustration purposes only, as this is definitely not recommendable or performant):

```
params = {'where': '{"$where":"this.username == \'Alex\'"}'}
```

With Eve's default settings (or `$where` included in MONGO_QUERY_BLACKLIST), the Eve API will return a response similar to the following:

> {"_status": "ERR", "_error": {"message": "The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.", "code": 400}}

Removing `$where` from the blacklist will return matching `_items`. I tested this against Eve 0.7.2 to confirm the expected behaviour.

Comment: This is correct. However, you can replace `where` keyword with one of your choice, see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

@Stennie is correct that `QUERY_MONGO_BLACKLIST` refers to actual query parameters, not the lookup keyword itself. However, if you want to disable filtering altogether just set `ALLOWED_FILTERS = []`.

Also, you can use `QUERY_WHERE` to pick another keyword if you do not want `where`:

```
# disable filters
ALLOWED_FILTERS = []
# replace the default 'where' with 'find'
QUERY_WHERE = 'find'
```

Comment: Thanks for the extra configuration tip! Aside from historical Eve API, is there a specific reason for the default choice of "where" versus "find"? If not, it might be helpful to better align the default configuration with MongoDB terminology.

Comment: I don't understand how ALLOWED_FILTERS works. I set it to void list as in your example, but ?where= still works.